# How can I embed a dll to the output assembly with codedom, and use it as reference using C#?

Tags: c#, dll, reference, embed, codedom

I have a class library dll which my generated program will use e.g. like this DLL.Do.Something(1); So I have to add this dll to codedom to embed it in the program and set it as reference. But I dont know how to do this and nobodí helped me yet...

Comment: why do you think they haven't help you? Maybe you should read the site's rules, *"What/How to ask here"*

Answer (score -1):

there are some confussing things in this question.
- do you have a third party dll? why cant you just reference it normally?
- you could use Assembly object to dinamilally load the dll into your domain without it being stringly referenced as:

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(sPath);
```

the you can get Types from that assembly and also use activator to create instances

but to be honest, this questions is too vague

good luck